# React router protected route with firebase auth check

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement protected routes and I use firebase for authentication. My browser freezes with this piece of code:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [authentication, setAuthState] = useState({
    authenticated: false,
    initializing: true
  });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      setAuthState({
        authenticated: true,
        initializing: false
      });
    } else {
      setAuthState({
        authenticated: false,
        initializing: false
      });
    }
  });

  if (authentication.initializing) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/"
            component={Home}
            authenticated={authentication.authenticated}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/join"
            component={Join}
            authenticated={authentication.authenticated}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/create"
            component={Create}
            authenticated={authentication.authenticated}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

I'm a React newbie and this is my first time with React hooks but what's wrong here ?

Comment: My guess is that it's because you're adding a new firebase event listener every time you render the App component. That's a lot of listeners whenever the state changes. It looks like you probably shouldn't use a FunctionComponent here because of that. Instead add the listener once when the component is mounted (or maybe even constructed)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that like iHowell explain in the comment, the firebase auth ... is a side effect, so you have to use the useEffect hook.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [authentication, setAuthState] = useState({
    authenticated: false,
    initializing: true
  });

  React.useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      setAuthState({
        authenticated: true,
        initializing: false
      });
    } else {
      setAuthState({
        authenticated: false,
        initializing: false
      });
    }
  }), [setAuthState]);

  if (authentication.initializing) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/"
            component={Home}
            authenticated={authentication.authenticated}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/join"
            component={Join}
            authenticated={authentication.authenticated}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/create"
            component={Create}
            authenticated={authentication.authenticated}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```