# Firebase authentication onAuthStateChanged responding after function body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an application with firebase. When loading any page, I am checking for authentication via following code. When I call isAuthenticated from landing page, its returning false even though user is already logged in and persistence is LOCAL(https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence), after false returned the inner function is executed.

> authentication.ts

```
import {auth} from "../firebase";

export function isAuthenticated() {
    console.log("Started!");
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) : boolean {
        console.log("Coming inside authentication");
        if (user) {
            console.log('User signed in - auth success! ', user.email);
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('User not signed in - auth failed! ');
            return false;
        }
    });
    console.log("Something wrong, coming here!");
    return false;
};
```

[image]

I am getting false even before the inner `onAuthStateChanged` function runs. Please look at the screen shot.

How to make sure I always get return value of inner function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auth.onAuthStateChanged` doesn't return anything helpful.  It adds a listener asynchronously that gets invoked whenever the user signs in or out.  It's not very useful for knowing the user state immediately, and you can't simply return a value out of the callback for use in an enclosing function.

If you want to know immediately if a user is currently signs in or out, you should just use [auth.currentUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#current-user) to get a User object.  It will be null if the user is signed out.  However, this status can change over time.  If you're interested in changes over time, use the listener instead.

Comment: I printed `auth.currentUser` in console at the top of isAuthenticated method, auth.currentuser is null, but authstatechanged returning true which is correct, I don't understand this behaviour, thank you.

Comment: That's because the current user might not be immediately available when a page loads.  In that case you will not be able to use currentUser, but you will also not be able to call any function.  You will have to wait until a listener tells you there is a signed in user in order to proceed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58769189/react-router-protected-route-with-firebase-auth-check
Found what I exactly needed, thank you for clarity.